# : Error creating bean with name 'productController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productRepository':

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm getting this exception :

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productRepository': No qualifying bean of type [domain.repository.ProductRepository] found for dependency [domain.repository.ProductRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [domain.repository.ProductRepository] found for dependency [domain.repository.ProductRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

May 02, 2020 5:18:48 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productRepository': No qualifying bean of type [domain.repository.ProductRepository] found for dependency [domain.repository.ProductRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [domain.repository.ProductRepository] found for dependency [domain.repository.ProductRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
```

Comment: Can you add the code for proper solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code and put the error message inside a code fragment so we can view the problem. Moreover, the error message indicates that you are trying to inject a dependency that doesn't exist (***ProductRepository***).

**possible cases:**

- You forgot to annotate your repository with the @Repository annotation. So Spring can't register it as a Bean.
- You are not component scanning the domain.repository package. So, once again Spring can't register anything inside this package as a Bean.